# Finding record by custom primaryKey

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My model is defined as follow:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  primaryKey: 'username',
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

My custom Adapter map:

```
DS.SocketAdapter.map('App.User', {
  primaryKey: 'username',
  username: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

I am testing this model out by typing on console:

```
App.User.createRecord({username:"user_1"});
var r = App.User.find("user_1");
console.log( r.serialize() );

>> Object {username: null, name: null ..... all null}
```

But it retuns a "null" Object. Also tested:

```
App.User.find({username:"user_1"});
```

But this is doing a remote request. I read that Ember Data does allow you to find records via attributes other than the ID.

So what I am doing wrong in telling Ember data my **custom primaryKey**?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the fact that you are defining `username` twice. if you map `username` from your json to your model's primaryKey trough your Adapter, then you should avoid to do the same on the model I guess. There are different approaches where to define the mapping, but the Adapter is the most appropriate place In your case, see here for more details: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#mapping

change your code like so and it should work:

```
// Model
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

// Adapter
DS.SocketAdapter.map('App.User', {
  primaryKey: 'username'
});
```

now try to create a new record

```
App.User.createRecord({username:"user_1", name:"foo"});
```

and then find the record by it's id as you already did:

```
var r = App.User.find("user_1");
```

this

```
console.log( r.serialize() );
```

should then give you at least:

```
>> Object {name: "foo" ...}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for reply! I cannot archive it! I created a jbin. http://jsbin.com/olizir/3/edit . Here is the output: http://jsbin.com/olizir/3 . In my real code I dont implement find() method of my adapter (because I am not interested of doing remote requestes, only finding a record by ID). Thanks

Comment: the you should use the `FixturesAdapter`, because the `RESTAdapter` is meant to do requests, so it only works if there is a find() and all such methods defined on the `RESTAdapter`. makes sense?

Comment: Refer to this link: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#revision-12 . What does mean "Custom sideloadAs and **key mappings** can still be configured to override these defaults as required"? What **key mappings** stands for? They are talking about primary keys? Thanks